# Incorrect quote in DataReader that is out of scope

Tags: pandas-datareader

I wrote some very simple lines:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

start = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,9,22)

f = web.DataReader("EWI", "yahoo", start, end)
f
```

However, the answer that I get is "slightly" wrong:

```
            Open        High        Low         Close       Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2017-09-19  31.410000   31.520000   31.360001   31.490000   31.490000   477100
2017-09-20  31.410000   31.500000   31.209999   31.379999   31.379999   885500
2017-09-21  31.370001   31.480000   31.350000   31.430000   31.430000   739600
2017-09-22  31.469999   31.610001   31.469999   31.510000   31.510000   447300
```

I'm getting the quotes for 2017-09-19 that were not asked for.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

It's curious that you are still getting data for 2017-09-22, because what I'm seeing for similar queries is that the DataReader API appears to be 1 (trading) day out. Have compared Panda's returned values with both yahoo and exchange data through my web browser, and Pandas is mislabelling the date! (it's a day behind). I'm basing my conclusion from matching of volume data.

Example: RIO.AX

Panda's Data

```
2017-10-19  68.599998  69.309998  68.389999  69.059998  69.059998  1855165.0
```

Yahoo Finance Site:

```
20 Oct. 2017    68.60   69.31   68.39   69.06   69.06   1,855,165
```

From the ASX site, this volume figure  is also confirmed as being from 20-10-2017